# How can i convert a script tag that is defined as string to a JSX object?

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I want to add some scripts that i call from api with Helmet package or without any other packages.The type of these scripts is string.
Assume that i put one of these scripts into a variable, And i want to add it to DOM.

`let myScript = "<script>alert('hello)</script>";`

When i add my variable to Helmet on this way, nothing will execute, because my script type is string.

`<Helmet>{myScript}</Helmet>`

While, if i do the task like the following, it would be added.

`let myScript = <script>alert('hello)</script>`

.

.

.

`<Helmet>{myScript}</Helmet>`

Does anyone know how i can convert my variable to JSX object that adds to DOM by Helmet?

Comment: Do you absolutely need the `<script></script>` tags? If not, you can convert your script to a function and call it within `<Helmet></Helmet>`

Comment: The strings would be read with `<script></script>` from api. How can i put them into `<Helmet></Helmet>` with function? @Nerdragen

Comment: If the `<script></script>` is absolutely necessary, the most braindead method I can come up with is to just regex those out and then have the actual script as a string inside the `<Helmet></Helmet>`

Comment: Can you explain it with an example? @Nerdragen

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the best solution, but you can replace both scripts with nothing, then just inject the code directly into helmet:

```
let myScript = "<script>alert('hello)</script>";
myScript = myScript.replace('<script>', '')
myScript = myScript.replace('</script>', '')
```

then in the return

```
<Helmet>
    <script>
        {myScript}
    </script>
</Helmet>
```

Honestly, in my opinion, it's not very good design to have your backend send anything with script tags attached, nor a good design to send raw JS from backend to be injected into the HTML  tag with an API call. React-Helmet also has an option to set innerHTML, but that already goes against React paradigms.

Comment: It is a good way, but if the script tag has attribute, it couldnt be done.(`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.com/t.js"></script>`)

Comment: There usually aren't any things that are truly "impossible" in programming. If you're100% sure that you'll only have `type` and `src` tags, then you can use regex to capture it, then add it to the React `script` tag.